# I am failing to build VirtualBox driver for Linux 2.6.38

Tags: kernel, compiling, virtualbox, kernel-modules

I am running Debian 6, and decided to install 2.6.38 kernel from Unstable. I also installed the headers so that I can later on :

```
sudo apt-get install --target-release=unstable linux-image-2.6.38-2-686-bigmem linux-headers-2.6.38-2-686-bigmem
```

I then re-installed **`virtualbox-ose-dkms`** to that the VirtualBox drivers for 2.6.38 can be rebuilt (so that I can use VirtualBox under 2.6.38), but I get this error:

```
Building initial module for 2.6.38-2-686-bigmem

Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 2.6.38-2-686-bigmem (i686)
Consult the make.log in the build directory
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose/3.2.10/build/ for more information.
dpkg: error processing virtualbox-ose-dkms (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
configured to not write apport reports
                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-ose-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here's the contents of the file they asked me to look at:

```
$ cat /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose/3.2.10/build/make.log 
DKMS make.log for virtualbox-ose-3.2.10 for kernel 2.6.38-2-686-bigmem (i686)
Sat Apr  9 14:11:57 SAST 2011
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-2-686-bigmem'
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose/3.2.10/build/built-in.o
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose/3.2.10/build/vboxdrv/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose/3.2.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose/3.2.10/build/include/VBox/types.h:30,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose/3.2.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/../SUPDrvInternal.h:35,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose/3.2.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:33:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose/3.2.10/build/include/iprt/types.h:97:31: error: linux/autoconf.h: No such file or directory
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose/3.2.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c: In function ‘VBoxDrvLinuxInit’:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose/3.2.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:451: error: ‘nmi_watchdog’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose/3.2.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:451: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose/3.2.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:451: error: for each function it appears in.)
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose/3.2.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:451: error: ‘NMI_IO_APIC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose/3.2.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:465: error: ‘nmi_active’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make[4]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose/3.2.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose/3.2.10/build/vboxdrv] Error 2
make[2]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose/3.2.10/build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-2-686-bigmem'
```

Comment: That missing `linux/autoconf.h` looks suspicious. Does `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-2-686-bigmem/include/linux/autoconf.h` exist? If it doesn't, your kernel headers are incomplete. If it does, there's a bug in a makefile somewhere that causes it not to look in the right directories.

Comment: It's instead found in `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-2-686-bigmem/include/generated/autoconf.h`. This is in comparison to 2.6.32's `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-686-bigmem/include/linux/autoconf.h`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`autoconf.h` [moved from `include/linux` to `include/generated`](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git-commits-head/2009/12/17/20634) in Linux [2.6.33](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.33/Makefile#L345). Authors of third-party modules must adapt their code; this has already been [done upstream for VirtualBox](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.emulators.virtualbox.devel/3594). In the meantime, you can [either patch the module source or create a symbolic link as a workaround](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&p=173096).

As for the NMI-related errors, the [NMI watchdog has changed a lot between 2.6.37 and 2.6.38](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=history;f=arch/x86/include/asm/nmi.h;h=4886a68f267e8b4a45eb9c872595b37d21c238ac;hb=HEAD). This looks like it requires a nontrivial porting effort on the module source code. In the meantime, you might have [some luck just patching out the offending code](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-871025.html). The purpose of the [NMI watchdog](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/nmi_watchdog.txt) is to debug kernel lockups, so it's something you can live without.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issues with the kernel 2.6.38.2 and in order to make things done I did, as root:

```
aptitude purge virtualbox-ose virtualbox-ose-dkms
dpkg --list |grep "^rc" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo dpkg --purge
locate -e virtualbox
```

I removed all related files excerpt my ~/.VirtualBox

then

```
- aptitude install virtualbox-ose virtualbox-ose-dkms
```

since, I have a running Virtualbox-ose 4.0.2 with a kernel 2.6.38.2

Comment: You may have missed the part where I'm using VBox 3.2.10.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that.... 
I upgrade squeezy to whezzy due to this issue.. Only way I've found to solve the pb....

Comment: [This answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10962/i-am-failing-to-build-virtualbox-driver-for-linux-2-6-38/10964#10964) helped, so am still a Squeeze user :)